# CNN_ how to use different sizes of input and output images?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have different sizes of input and output images. How can I use CNN algorithm for image prediction? I do not want to adjust the size of the images. For example, the input should be 32x32x3 and output 64x64x3. If I can use global maximum or average pooling, the size of inputs will be 1x1x128 (128=#of channels).

Comment: what do you mean by image prediction? Is it classification of image into pre-defined categories?

Comment: @dhruv tailor, I meant image to image regression. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can search for u-net or v-net structures